# Is it possible to get 120 stars on the Android version of Crayon Physics Deluxe?

Tags: android, crayon-physics-deluxe

The last level of Crayon Physics Deluxe requires 120 stars to unlock. This means you have to play through every level in the game and obtain both an Elegant solution and an Old School solution for each of them. For many of the latter levels (and even a few of the earlier ones) this seems to be impossible.

A quick search online indicates that people have been [modifying the game's XML files](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/955725-crayon-physics-deluxe/51380304) to lower this number to a more reasonable number (and apparently the ability to play online, though this does not appear to be possible on the Android version of the game), but is the 120 stars actually achivable without cheating on Android?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible since I had got more than 120 stars due to my perseverance.

[image: 120]

Comment: I don't remeber wether this is on my PC or on my android. If someone know that it is on PC, I will delete this answer.